# java iterator throwing awt-eventqueue exception

Tags: java, iterator

I'm writing a program that adds items to a list and uses an iterator to print all of the items to a JTextArea. I'm a little confused because I thought it was because if there is no next, I'm trying to print a null statement, but doesn't the condition of the while loop check if there's a next object in the iterator?

I know the issue is only with the println, since if I remove it the program works fine. However, is there a way I can access the next object in the iterator as a string?

```
while (iter.hasNext())
  {
     System.out.println(iter.next().toString());
     i++;
     r = i + " x " + formatter.formatLineItem(iter.next());
  }
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out-of-bounds for length 2
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:440)
at Invoice$1.next(Invoice.java:56)
at Invoice$1.next(Invoice.java:48)
at Invoice.format(Invoice.java:80)
```

It's throwing a "AWT-Eventqueue-0" exception. I'm currently using the println to be able to see what exactly which items are in the iterator because I want to classify each item by name. However, I want to be able to access the string of the item that's in the iterator.

Comment: You call `iter.next()` twice after only one check to `iter.hasNext()`. Also, is this a custom `Iterator`? If there's no more elements then `next()` should throw `NoSuchElementException`, not `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: How can I refer to the same iter.next for both calls?

Comment: Store the result in a local variable, then use the variable to reference the element.